# shapely.nearest_points wrong result: floating point error?

Tags: geopandas, distance, shapely, tolerance

I am loading a `.shp` file through GeoPandas that consists of several LineStrings that should be united, but they are not. So I would like to unite them.

I am using `shapely.nearest_points` and creating a LineString that connects those closest points, but the resulting points are not always in the given line.

Example:

```py
line1 = shapely.LineString([
        (-76.7532261503939, 37.29939869335629), (-76.75323025230898, 37.299396172262654), (-76.75336366152584, 37.299323929074134)
    ])

line2 = shapely.LineString([
    (-76.7525401791729, 37.299815181622705), (-76.75282347819562, 37.29964617973539), (-76.7532261503941, 37.29939869335629)
])

nearest = shapely.ops.nearest_points(line1, line2)
print(nearest[0].distance(line1))

>>> 1.7692869138383317e-15
```

where the expected printed value should be `0.0`.

In fact, plotting the map and zooming in, we get:

```py
gpd.GeoDataFrame({
    'id': ['line1', 'line2', 'point1', 'point2'],
    'geometry': [line1, line2, nearest[0], nearest[1]]
}).explore()
```

[image: Zoomed map]

I am trying to understand what is happening, but I can't find any information. Can it be a floating point tolerance error?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a floating point error. Numbers like 1.7692869138383317e-15 are close to [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) for double precision, and they are usually unavoidable with diagonal lines. Nice distance numbers could be expected if the lines and closest point pairs were perpendicular to the coordinate system.

You could consider these geometries intersect if they are within a small distance, e.g. 2e-15.